# How can my bot say (in vocal) a text from a string? Like Google Translate

Tags: javascript, string, discord, discord.js, voice

All I want is my bot saying the name of the person who joined the vocal. I want my bot to "read" a string.

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const say = require('say')

const bot = new Discord.Client();
require("dotenv").config()

let prefix = "!"
//              officiel                             test
let global = /*"276150994189025302"*/          "847683020928450590"

bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot online!")
})

bot.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return
    let MessageArray = message.content.split(" ")
    let cmd = MessageArray[0].slice(prefix.length)
    let args = MessageArray.slice(1)
    let globalchan = message.guild.channels.cache.get(global)

    if(cmd == "ping") {
        globalchan.send("Pong")
    }
})

bot.on("voiceStateUpdate", async (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(newMember.member.user.bot) return    
    if(newMember.channelID == null) {
        let channel = bot.channels.cache.get(oldMember.channelID)
        channel.leave()
    }else{
        newMember.member.voice.channel.join()
    }
    
})

bot.on("guildMemberSpeaking", (member, state) => {
    if(member.user.bot) return
    if(state.bitfield == 1) {
        console.log("parle")
        say.speak(member.user.username)
    }
    
})
```

Comment: Unrelated note: `global` isn't the best variable name.

Comment: If you want the bot to speak in the VC, what you will need is a Text-to-Speech (TTS) service.

Comment: All you need to do is find a TTS service. You can look around on NPM for a module providing such a feature, there are hundreds of them available. In fact, you could even use Google's own TTS service, available in various modules such as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-tts-api).